# Sort objects by a substring of a model field in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Im trying to find best solution to sort through all Machine objects in my db and find last deviceSerialNo used.

deviceSerialNo is a character field and has a structure like this: AB12-12344.

My task is to sort all Machine objects by a substring of deviceSerialNo field(everything after '-' in deviceSerialNo.
My current solution that kind of works

`last = Machine.objects.all().order_by('-deviceSerialNo').first().deviceSerialNo`

or

`last2 = Machine.objects.all().order_by('-deviceSerialNo').annotate(search_index=StrIndex('deviceSerialNo', V('-'))).first().deviceSerialNo`

Can someone help me sort it as I mentioned above?

Comment: Is the part before '-' always 4 characters long?

Comment: No its not. Its changing depending on which model was selected

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can order by a field created with annotate:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Value as V
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, StrIndex, Substr

last = (
    Machine.objects.annotate(
        part=Cast(Substr("deviceSerialNo", StrIndex("deviceSerialNo", V("-"))), IntegerField())
    )
    .order_by("part")
    .first()
    .deviceSerialNo
)
```

Just like you had we start by getting the index of the `-` character:

```
StrIndex('deviceSerialNo', V('-'))
```

We then take use [`Substr`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Substr) to get the second part including the `-` character:

```
Substr("deviceSerialNo", StrIndex("deviceSerialNo", V("-")))
```

Then we cast it to an IntegerField, sort and get the first object. Note: We can get the first object as the integer cast of `"-12344"` is a negative number.

Comment: how to change this code so it will now check for a regular expression match: AB123-02506 and get only number after the -02? Number after -02 will only grow now

Comment: And number -02 can be anything between 01 and 12

Comment: @ikkuh is there a way to get the index of the last index of the character? For example if the string instead was `AB-12-12344`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "the index of the last index of the character". You might want to open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If number have multiple - and want to extract out number from reverse then try following. AB-12-12344

Output: 12344

```
qs.annotate(
   r_part=Reverse('number')
).annotate(
   part=Reverse(
        Cast(
             Substr("r_part", 1, StrIndex("r_part", V("-")))
        ), 
        IntegerField()
    )
```

)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the objects using the extra() function:

```
your_objects = Machine.objects.all()
your_objects = your_objects.extra(select={'str_deviceSerialNo':'SUBSTRING("deviceSerialNo",initial_char,last_char)'}).order_by('str_deviceSerialNo')
```

It worked for me.